# Como implementar Buffer.alloc() y Buffer.from() en angular 5

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, typescript

tengo estas líneas de código las cuales funcionan en node.js

```js
let seed = "123456789"
let out = Buffer.alloc(93, "hex")
let salt = Buffer.from(seed, "hex")
```

Pero necesito algo equivalente o igual que me de el mismo resultado que Buffer.alloc() y Buffer.from() en angular 5 o ionic 3

estoy usando la libreria: https://www.npmjs.com/package/libsodium-wrappers-sumo,

la cual tiene los métodos pad(, ) y unpad(, )

, pero no tengo claro cómo implementarlos

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"
import * as _sodium from "libsodium-wrappers-sumo"
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

@Injectable()
export class Provider {
  constructor(
    public buffer:Buffer
  ) {
 
    (async () => {
      await _sodium.ready
      let seed = "123456789"
      let out = _sodium.pad(93, "hex")
      let salt = _sodium.unpad(seed, "hex")
      
      //pad(<buffer>, <block size>), unpad(<buffer>, <block size>)


    })()
  }
}
```